# How does React's JSX breakout an array through interpolation?

Tags: html, arrays, reactjs, markup, jsx

I'm following the [Thinking in React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and on Part 2 below see that the var `rows` is interpolated into the markup through JSX. How does JSX know to break out each markup item inside the array? Because to me, the interpolation of `{rows}` will simply return an **array** of markup rather than each markup row laid out one by one. So I see it returning `[rowA, rowB, ...]` instead of `<rowA /> <rowB /> ...`

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var rows = [];
        var lastCategory = null;
        this.props.products.forEach(function (product) {
            if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
                rows.push(
                    <ProductCategoryRow
                        category={product.category}
                        key={product.category}
                    />
                );
            }
            rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
            lastCategory = product.category;
        });
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly braces are a way to execute arbitrary JavaScript expressions inline (including a simple object) and have React evaluate that and render the result.

When React sees `{rows}`, this is what it thinks:

"oh cool, I have a variable to render. Oh look, it's an array! What's in the array? Oh I see that the first item is a React element called `ProductCategoryRow`, I'll go render that. NEXT! I see the next one is a `ProductRow`, I'll go render that"

and so on.

Since you're the curious type :) [here's the source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/shared/utils/traverseAllChildren.js#L90) that seems to check to see if the item is an Array, if so it renders each item as it would any single item.

Comment: so the curly braces of {} doesn't just mean evaluate this expression but also render what's inside of it? looking at the docs I couldn't find anything on this. Does this work the same way if I give it an object with keys that are React elements?

Answer (score 3):

This is what the former `JSXTransformer`, now `Babel`, does. It traverses the JSX syntax and generates valid JavaScript. When it finds a `{}` construct...

- If it's a literal, return it.
- If it's JavaScript expression, evaluate it and return it (in case the result is a `React Element`, *transforms* it)
- If it's a `React Element`, *transform* it.
- If it's an Array or `React Element`, *transform* each one individually and return each of them.

The above list is probably not complete but you get the picture.